# Which questions can I flag?

Tags: support, flagging

I want to clarify this. I flagged [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/803324/can-anyone-help-with-sound) question as I felt it is not about Ubuntu. Am I wrong?

Comment: I would've flagged it unclear, since it's possible to install Ubuntu on a Chromebook and I think it's possible to install Kodi on Ubuntu, but from the quality of the question and the lack of the mention of Ubuntu, OT is fine. 3 other people agree with you (I can see the close votes).

Comment: What made you think it isn't about Ubuntu? What did your flag say? Please clarify.

Comment: @Zacharee1 why? As you said, chromebooks can run Ubuntu and Kodi can also run on Ubuntu. I see nothing that makes the question off topic. It is not very good and could use some clarification, true. Perhaps after the clarification, we'll be able to decide that it is off topic but I don't see enough information to decide that now.

Comment: @Zacharee1 Thank you. I understood my fault. :)

Comment: @terdon Thank you very much for explaining me. I understand what's wrong with my flag. This is a good lesson. :)

Comment: It would also be nice for one of the flaggers to leave a comment explaining what is wrong and how to fix it. We should try to improve bad questions, not just flag them for removal and move on.

Comment: @MarkKirby I understand and will follow your advice hereafter.. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was the moderator who handled your flag, so I'm going to give you the basic rundown of my thoughts when handling the flag.

As stated in the comments, you flagged as "Not about Ubuntu".  With regards to this question, the question mentions "Kodi", but that is ambiguous - there is an application suite called "Kodi" (which can be installed onto Linux distributions), and also a Linux distribution called "Kodi Linux" (also known as Kodibuntu, which you can use interchangeably for this case).  It is not clear which the poster of the question is asking about - the software suite or the OS.  The reason it is unclear is as follows:

- If the poster of the question is using Kodibuntu, then it is **off-topic** here.  This is because Kodibuntu is not an official derivative of Ubuntu and would not be on-topic here.  (see the [help center document about what topics can be asked here](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic) for more on this).
- If the poster of the question is using Ubuntu, and installed the Kodi software onto Ubuntu (and did not install Kodibuntu), then it is **on-topic** here, as their core operating system is Ubuntu or an official Ubuntu derivative, and they are asking for assistance with a specific piece of software running in an actual Ubuntu (or official derivative) installation.

Because of this unclear nature of the question, and the above reasoning of why I can't just say it's "offtopic" and "not ubuntu", I declined your flag.  When posed with an unclear question, it is more useful to flag as 'Unclear' and to post a comment trying to get clarification from the question poster, so we can get information to better assess whether the question is on topic, or so we can gather information to help the poster.  If we get a response, then the response would help dictate where the question belongs - here on Ask Ubuntu, or elsewhere.  Without a response, the question remains unclear, which has its own close reason.

For now, I've closed the question as unclear.  (There were four close votes for "Not about Ubuntu", but as I said here, there's not enough information to clarify whether it is or is not about Ubuntu, so "Unclear what you're asking" was selected by me.)